# Ajax unwanted display of result

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is from a register form. This function verifies if the username is available or not.

jQuery:

```
    /* Verifies if the username is available */
    $.post('functions/usernameDisponibility.php',{usernamePHP:username},function(disponibility)
    {
            $('.usernameErrors').text(disponibility);

    if(disponibility==true)
    {
        $('#username').css('border-color','#00ff00');
    }else
        {
            $('#username').css('border-color','red');
            $('.usernameErrors').text('Username unavailable');
        }
    });
```

PHP:

```
    if(isset($_POST['usernamePHP'])&&!empty($_POST['usernamePHP']))
{
    $username = $_POST['usernamePHP'];

    $Connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
                mysql_select_db('phplogin');

    $query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");

    $result= mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($result==1)
    {
        echo false;
    }else
    {
        echo true;
    }
}
```

The problem is in the error display. When disponibility != true, it shows "Username unavailable", but when it's true it shows "1". My guess is that "1" came from the PHP script but even if I do this:

```
            if(disponibility==true)
        {
            $('#username').css('border-color','#00ff00');
            $('.usernameErrors').text('');
        }else
```

The "1" still shows up very quickly and only then it is replace by text(''). What can I do for the "1" not be displayed at all?

Comment: Unrelated: *Please* read about [SQL Injections](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)!

Comment: Ya, I know, I know. mysql_real_escape_string. I didn't write it the code here because it doesn't matter for the problem. But thanks anyway ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because of this:

```
$('.usernameErrors').text(disponibility);
```

you are outputing the content of "disponibility" variable before you do any checks. Remove that line

Comment: I tried that. The "1" shows up really quickly and then disapears. But it still shows up =/

Comment: @user1606963 clear you browser cache and try again. if you removed that line then it shouldn't print anymore